# not able to hover on multiple tabs in a for each loop using webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a form editor web application for creating forms and workflows. The home page of the application contains a menu on the left side.

The menu looks like [image].

when I mouseover any tab, I get a tool tip.

I am currently trying to verify this using selenium webdriver and c#. Following is the HTML for the menu

```
<div class="tabmenu">
    <div class="tab-list">
        <div class="mask"></div>
    <ul class="level1" style="left: 0px;">
        <li class="l1-item top" title="">
            <span class="selection-top"></span>
            <table class="mover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tooltip">
                            <span>Create Flow</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="logo logo12">
                                <span class="status status-none"></span>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <span class="selection-bottom"></span>
            <div class="hr"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="l1-item prev" title="">
            <span class="selection-top"></span>
            <table class="mover" style="left: -110px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tooltip">
                            <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span class="logo logo11">
                                <span class="status status-none"></span>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <span class="selection-bottom"></span>
            <div class="hr"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I mouseover any tab, the `<li class="l1-item>` have another class added `<li class="l1-item tooltip">`

Following is the code that I have written

```
    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "ul.level1 > li")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IList<IWebElement> LeftMenuItems;

    public bool isToolTipPresentOnEachTab()
    {
        foreach (IWebElement ele in LeftMenuItems)
        {
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(ele).Perform();
            if((ele.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td.tooltip > span")).GetAttribute("textContent")) != "Create Flow"
                    && !ele.GetAttribute("class").Contains("showtooltip")){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am getting the tooltip only in the first iteration of the loop and the test fails in the 2nd iteration.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: What is the IF condition supposed to do here?

Comment: Since your first iteration succeeds I suggest that try to add a wait (~1s) after action.MoveToElement(ele).Perform();, to see if it its just a matter of waiting for the tooltip to appear.

Comment: if condition checks for a particular tab name for which the tool tip wont appear so just want to return false in case for all the other tabs the tool tip don't appear.

Comment: Did you try adding a wait as in my previous comment?

Comment: yes I tried that but there is no impact of the wait. Looking for some other workaround for now :)

Comment: Why does it fail? Because of the tooltip is not found, or is it that your variable ele does not contain the correct elements?

Comment: Its because the class attribute is not getting updated. While i perform the operation manually, the functionality works fine. somehow its failing continuously in automation

Comment: If that is the case, it sounds like the hover you are trying to do has no effect. Are you sure that you are hovering the correct element, ie the element that triggers the tooltip effect?

Comment: yes. As for one of the elements it is working through automation everytime. For rest of the 2 items it is not working fine. And manually it works for all the elements. I have cross verified the css selector as well. I also doubt the hovering is is not working correctly through my code. I can observe that while running my code